# Magento2 Free Shipping method is not shown

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I have enabled Free Shipping method in the back-end and no other method is enabled.

When I checkout adding just one product, sometimes the free-shipping method is shown and some-times it is not.
besides there is a message above free shipping method as

"No quotes is available for this order at this time"

but still I am able to checkout without any issue when Free shipping Method is shown.

I also observed that when I add more than 1 product, the shipping method is invariably shown without any issue.

What could be the reason for this?

I have not added any shipping rule.